# Salesforce RestResource GET API is unable to identify special characters passed in query string

Tags: apex, api, restresource, get

I have created a RestResource API class with GET method. It is supposed to accept the email passed as an input via the query string, and perfom logic based on that email received.

It all worked fine until I received an input that consists of special character '+' in the email.

Email passed as query string : test@test+14@gmail.com
Email showing in debug logs  : test@test 14@gmail.com

And because of that the entire flow breaks down and the desired result is not obtained.

Can anyone please suggest what could be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: Passing emails in via a query string sounds like the seeds of a data breach waiting to happen. If you're planning on making this public, you should carefully consider the security implications (e.g. this API you're making could expose the fact that certain email addresses are either used or not used). Knowing that `admin@myCompany.tld` is not available means that's one less piece of information an attacker needs to guess (and is a driving reason behind why login pages tend not to tell you that the email is wrong, but rather that "the email or password is wrong")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is a "reserved character" in URLs; it represents a space character. Also, `@` is a reserved character. To pass in a literal `+`, use %2B, and for `@`, use %40, as in:

```
test%40test%2814%40gmail.com
```

There are other characters you need to look out for, too. See [Percent Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) for more details.

Also, generally speaking, any Unicode character that doesn't fit in a single byte also needs to be encoded with percent encoding as well.